# If equipped items become bound to you, where do all the items in the auction house come from?

Tags: spiral-knights

I bought a recipe for a shield, and equipped it hoping to sell it when I was done. Turns out you have to learn a recipe to use it, which makes it non-tradable anymore, and kind of useless afterwards.

I then bought the materials I was missing and completed the item. I then noticed that once equipped the item would be bound to me, and I wouldn't be able to sell it anymore.

If all items that are used can't be traded anymore, where do all the items in the auction house come from? Are some items found in depth? Is it just people continuing to craft items for the sole purpose of selling them to other people?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are from people crafting them for the sole purpose of selling them.  One of the good things about buying a recipe is that it is not only cheaper than buying the item itself, but you can then use the recipe to put together those raw materials again to make an item to sell, hopefully for more than you would've gotten for just the raw materials.  Note that crafted items will sometimes get [special attributes](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Unique_variant) that you can't get on dropped/store-bought items, making them even more valuable.

Comment: So, for example, a [Valkyrie Mail](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Valkyrie_Mail) can never be put for sale because it requires a level 10 item, and the only way to level up is equipping and thus binding the item right?

Comment: Since the crafting page says "Note: When crafting using a bound item as a precursor, the upgraded item will also be bound.", I would say you are correct.

Comment: Items can now be unbound

Comment: @bwarner While this may be an uber-necro bump, the last sentence doesn't hold true, because another NPC can add random UV's to your Gear

Answer (score 3):

Note that some items can be unbound via [Vise](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Vise), who can unbind your items for you, but at a fee (quite a hefty one at that).

```
         Item   ↓        Energy (CE)↓
Unbind 1 Star Ticket        100
Unbind 2 Star Ticket        200
Unbind 3 Star Ticket        600
Unbind 4 Star Ticket        1800
Unbind 5 Star Ticket        4000
```

That's why you see some 5* items in the AH.  You can't craft it up to a 5* without investing heat, and heat only comes from journeying through the clockworks, which means some users have the items bound to them, then unbind when they've hit 5*.

Comment: Do you remember when they added the option for that? About one year ago IIRC

Comment: @Sentry I believe so yeah. I don't think I was around SK when they introduced, but looking at the revision history on the wiki, looks like it was released on Jul 20, 2011